# grub equivalent of append parameter in txt.cfg

Tags: grub

We're using a custom Ubuntu 20.04 and need to pass variables during boot. On 16.04, we were using ISOLINUX boot loader and our txt.cfg looked like this:

```
label m1
  menu label Install srv (SINGLE DISK)
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append auto file=/cdrom/preseed/srv_preseed _C=param1 _S=param2
```

param1 and param2 were then available as environment variables in the boot environment.

With Ubuntu 20.04 we then switched to UEFI and that made a change to grub necessary. Our grub.cfg looks like this:

```
menuentry "srv" {
                set gfxpayload=keep
                linux   /casper/vmlinuz _C=param1 "ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/inst/" quiet autoinstall ---
                initrd  /casper/initrd
}
```

However, _C=param1 is not available in the boot environment.

What's the correct way to pass these parameters? Is there anything else we're missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, I believe you are using the 16.04 "server" installer and the 20.04 "live-server" installer.  The old "server" installer (based on `debian-installer`) is being phased out for the new "live-server" installer (based on `subiquity`).  For 20.04, the old "server" image was renamed "legacy-server".

If you use [a legacy-server image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/) then you could keep using your 16.04 technique.

If you use the "live-server" image then it depends where you want to use the environment variables.  A generic solution is to modify `/etc/environment` in the installer environment.

This is a partial `user-data` file for `autoinstall` that will use `cloud-init` to add variables to `/etc/environment` in the installer environment.  Using a shell to check the output in `/run/my_env.txt` will show that the custom environment variables are present for the installer process.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  early-commands:
    - env | sort >> /run/my_env.txt
write_files:
  - path: /etc/environment
    content: |
      _C=param1
      _S=param2
    append: true
```

If you want to keep using kernel arguments to set variables then a more creative solution could get the variables from PID 1.  This is a partial `user-data` file that assumes the kernel arguments to be used as environment variables begin with `_`.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  early-commands:
    - env | sort >> /run/my_env.txt
bootcmd:
  - cat /proc/1/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | grep ^_ >> /etc/environment
```